# I can't change the boolean value of the User model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to change a boolean field in an abstract user model in Django from False to True but I can't do it.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile-pictures', blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


def View(request):
    user = request.user
    
    print(user.username)
    user.boolean is True
    print(user.is_vendor)
    user.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
```

Comment: You are not changing `user.boolean` in your View. With `user.boolean` you are just comparing the values. Use `user.boolean = True` to actually change it.

Answer (score 2):

You save this with:

```
def View(request):
    user = request.user
    print(user.username)
    user.boolean = True
    print(user.is_vendor)
    user.save()
    # …
```

The `is` operator is only used to *check* if two objects are the same. Likely `user.boolean is True` will be `False`, but it will not assign anything to the `.boolean` attribute.